# Error when trying to use SELECT...FOR UPDATE in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I've been trying to execute this line command:

```
START TRANSACTION; SELECT * FROM users where uid = 1 FOR UPDATE
```

in phpMyAdmin. It is throwing an error when I do so:

> **SQL query:**
>
> `SELECT * FROM users where uid = 1 FOR UPDATE LIMIT 0, 25`
>
> **MySQL said:**
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

What I am trying to do is to implement exclusive record locking when an update query is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html, LIMIT needs to come before FOR UPDATE. So changing your query to the following should get you past this error:

```
START TRANSACTION; SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = 1 LIMIT 0, 25 FOR UPDATE;
```

Comment: That was working fine. But now I want to update as well . I am using this command: "START TRANSACTION; SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = 1 LIMIT 0, 25 FOR UPDATE; UPDATE users SET name = "Marcose" WHERE uid = 1 COMMIT;" But this is not working. It throws this error "- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'COMMIT' at line 1"

Comment: Once again, the docs for `update` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) has working examples you can look at. I'm betting you need a `;` to close the `UPDATE` before `COMMIT;`

Comment: That query worked with no errors. but it is not giving me the desired output. If I execute the query "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = 1 LIMIT 0, 25 FOR UPDATE;" And then I try to update after this , it is updating immediately and not giving any sings of a locked record. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: I'm not sure. You'd need to provide more detail about the issue, but please do some research and/or post another question on the site for this issue. [Comments aren't for extended discussion; especially on an answered question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).